# Filter products by attribute in PrestaShop in php

Tags: prestashop, product

I am more than novice in php, I understand parts of the code but most do not understand.

I'm modifying a module that exports PrestaShop products to a PDF based on the selected category.

Now, I want the "get" function to get all the active products, but not those that are enabled as "online_only".

The part of the code that calls the products is this:

```
    public function getContent()
{
    $context = Context::getContext();
    $langmod = $context->langmod;
    $products = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach (Tools::getValue('categoryBox') as $osque) {
        $productget = Product::getProducts(Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'ASC', $osque, $active = true);
        $products[$i]['products'] = $productget;
        $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $sql = '
        SELECT `name`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang`
        WHERE `id_category` = '.(int)$osque.'
        AND `id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang;
        $name = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
        $products[$i]['categorie'] = $name;
        $i++;
    }
```

The boolean variable that checks this is:

```
online_only = true
online_only = false
```

So i tried modifyng this line of code:

```
$productget = Product::getProducts(Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'ASC', $osque, $active = true, $online_only = false);
```

But I get a blank page..

Any help?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this override (in override/classes/Product.php):

```
<?php
class ProductCore extends ProductCore
{
    public static function getProducts($id_lang, $start, $limit, $order_by, $order_way, $id_category = false,
        $only_active = false, Context $context = null, $pdf = false)
    {
        if (!$context)
        $context = Context::getContext();

    $front = true;
    if (!in_array($context->controller->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront')))
        $front = false;

    if (!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way))
        die (Tools::displayError());
    if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'price' || $order_by == 'date_add' || $order_by == 'date_upd')
        $order_by_prefix = 'p';
    else if ($order_by == 'name')
        $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
    else if ($order_by == 'position')
        $order_by_prefix = 'c';

    if (strpos($order_by, '.') > 0)
    {
        $order_by = explode('.', $order_by);
        $order_by_prefix = $order_by[0];
        $order_by = $order_by[1];
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, pl.* , m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, s.`name` AS supplier_name
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` '.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m ON (m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`)
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'supplier` s ON (s.`id_supplier` = p.`id_supplier`)'.
            ($id_category ? 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` c ON (c.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)' : '').'
            WHERE pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.
                ($id_category ? ' AND c.`id_category` = '.(int)$id_category : '').
                ($pdf ? ' AND p.`online_only` = 0' : '').
                ($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').
                ($only_active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '').'
            ORDER BY '.(isset($order_by_prefix) ? pSQL($order_by_prefix).'.' : '').'`'.pSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way).
            ($limit > 0 ? ' LIMIT '.(int)$start.','.(int)$limit : '');
    $rq = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);
    if ($order_by == 'price')
        Tools::orderbyPrice($rq, $order_way);

    foreach ($rq as &$row)
        $row = Product::getTaxesInformations($row);

    return ($rq);
}
}
```

And with in your code :

```
$productget = Product::getProducts(Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'ASC', $osque, true, null, true);
```

*To avoid the hassle of caching thought to delete the file class_index.php in the cache folder at the root of your site.*

Regards

Comment: Hello ethercreation,

Comment: HI Diego Reyes ,

Comment: Ethercreation, I am willing to pay for making such modification in the module. Is it possible for us to contact each other privately?

Comment: Yes :=) contact me by MP

Comment: Thanks for your response, Ethercreation. I had already hired a developer from the PrestaShop forum, thanks anyway :) I already solved the problem :D